# Faced an Error while creating an add-on on Visual Studio using Selenium for G1ANT

Tags: visual-studio, g1ant

I faced this error while building my solution.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.26.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets.   G1ANT.Addon.Linkedin    C:\Users\Rishabh Mishra\source\repos\G1ANT.Addon.Linkedin\G1ANT.Addon.Linkedin.csproj
```

This is the only error showing. My G1ANT Sdk is correctly installed as well as i cleared all the dependencies.   What could be the possible fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this happens, I deleted the project tried it again. Create a new project and then try refreshing the dependencies. Therefore the G1ANT.Language dependencies. I corrected my error doing this, hope this helps!!